# Why is this leaking memory in ie 8?

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks, updatepanel

edit 2 -

To recreate - (I hope)

Create an empty asp.net project, add a default.aspx, and an about.aspx

use this code for the default.aspx file:

http://pastebin.com/4Ri1BufM

and this for about.aspx

http://pastebin.com/Ni9dZL7c

Build, and run sieve against it. Click the button, then the link.  Sieve should now list 1 memory leak.

This simple layout puts a server button inside a panel. If you click it, and then the "Leave" link, sIEve reports 1 memory leak:

```
http://localhost:2605/Default.aspx  (1 reference)
<INPUT value="partial postback" type=submit name=ctl01 >
```

Aspx source:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="LeakTestProject._Default" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button Text="partial postback" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
    <a href="SomeOtherPage.aspx" >leave</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I've think I've tracked down a memory leak in my application to this source.

Would anyone be able to explain why this is happening, and what to do to fix it?

(Note - there is no server side code running)

edit-

Here is the generated html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="Form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTUzNzM3OTMxMmRk27mKixZYS2MtHiuw7SZF6+1A/CkWRnnarcN2a05yCJs=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=_lxNoU5aYdEC_WWnUhGTN0VgFQnwFJ1fkZBkPhUGNITY1Tt87f4CGSPd9dhq2TD9I8lv5ljTGi956KpbHSLq3ebld0t7nKLON7Hc04CCAwA1&amp;t=634525784292792916" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=0VE3fsyoY2cTFnat6m0YjE4OCCjVV0jmjSC6wigMBEOHyKW8kewBrhtJnBFIn73VSWcGW45QXwelC5m-1iZoornC8qWpZ-kXP-Y38e49qW1TbssOgo419ZWtVHSVmIpSg9CvXOQzUBClAjuHORyX5Q2&amp;t=ffffffffbd2983fc" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=DBlWOXkmp0ycsSicGEZhACmLuhW1VF8BppK-Uj8ijyjhFxx7MTG8NW0gLl3IJ6TyEo2rAMfLCQ9rO_bk2wDCcpyT3Df6CN-TLMAA575gUNAjTSzC6U1koagV2FYRmu4TNsAgoEjhkN6fJX3lENf7Bw2&amp;t=ffffffffbd2983fc" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgLZvOXNBgKiwImNCx8fSMXEwq+V+5yrnoaTcidPwoJw3ebm6DJQ1D3fVVAL" />
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ScriptManager1', 'Form1', ['tUpdatePanel1','UpdatePanel1'], [], [], 90, '');
//]]>
</script>

    <div id="UpdatePanel1">

            <input type="submit" name="ctl01" value="partial postback" />

</div>
    </form>
    <a href="About.aspx" >leave</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So this is only in IE8? What about with Compatibility mode turned on? Have you tried disabling plugins on the browser to see if that does anything? What about firing up IE developer toolbar thing to see if you can see if there is any javascript polling going on or anything. Maybe use Firebug for the same purpose. From appearances it looks 'fine'.

Comment: @rangitatanz sieve only works for ie, but going back to the original application that was having the problems, it ran fine in chrome and ff.  I took a peek at the running script with the profiling tool, but it's running a few hundred functions inside 3 axd resource files, totallying about ~10k lines of javascript.

Comment: What version of .net are you running?

Comment: @rangitatanz vs 2010 sp1, .Net 4, ajaxtoolkit version 3.0.30930.28736

Comment: Have you confirmed this works on a diff clean install of IE8 on another laptop?

Comment: @rangitatanz Yes. I just pushed it  up to an internal test web server, and reran the test from a fresh ie8 loaded virtual machine. I'm seeing the same leak still.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to chuck a test project onto skydrive or somewhere for us to have a look at? Just with cut down stuff. I'm finding it hard to replicate.

Comment: @rangitatanz The posted code is the entire project.

Comment: could you post the generated html source - as seen by the browser and the output from sieve.
thanks

Comment: @memical Posted! The output from seive is already there.

Comment: @memical Edited with pastebin links to recreate easier hopefully.

Comment: i think the problem is the same as the one reported by rangitatanz below. If the controls have an event attached, they do not get garbaged collected in IE. since the submit button makes an ajax call to the server it must have a click event attached to it. try to set a breackpoint in the dopostback function and see where it is called from

Comment: @memical Two questions - 1: Since `__doPostBack` is inserted into the page by the ScriptManager at runtime, how do I set a breakpoint on it? 2: How do I see the where the call is coming from once I'm at the break point?  Very sorry if these are dumb questions, I'm by no means a javascript expert.

Comment: in IE, hit f12, the developer tools will open, if you go to the script tab you can set a BP in any js (this is client side, has nothing to do with VS). Once the BP is hit, there should be a call stack. the idea is to find the function that makes the ajax call. My guess is that a control has that event attached, and because of that it does not get garbage collected.

Comment: @memical One moment, lets give that a shot.

Comment: @memical I set a breakpoint in __doPostBack but it doesn't seem to be getting hit.

Comment: @memical I don't have any way of posting the project to an outside host from work. The posted code however, is the entire project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6070/discussion-between-memical-and-asawyer)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/jqmemleak.aspx there is a memory leak that sounds a lot like what you are experiencing.

See "Iteration 2 - Memory Leak"

Using a tool called 'SIEve' he states 'You can see that every time I click refresh, it creates a new set of input elements without destroying the previous ones. '

His fix was a JQuery plugin that calls into the Update panel cleanup hooks. You could potentially try this?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.Disposable = function(cln) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var el = this;
            if (!el.dispose) {
                el.dispose = cleanup; // will be called by 
                            // Microsoft for cleanup
            $(window).bind("unload", cleanup);
    }

    function cleanup() {
            if (!el)
                return;
            $(el).unbind();
            $(window).unbind("unload", cleanup);
            el.dispose = null;
            el = null;
        };
    });
    };
})(jQuery);

function add() {
    $get('res').value = 
        parseInt($get('i1').value) + parseInt($get('i2').value);
}
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
    $('.num').change(add).Disposable();
});
```

Comment: I've reviewed that page before. It's a script to allow you to clean up jQuery closures automatically when an update panel refresh happens. In the example, there is no jQuery loaded. No user javascript at all.

Comment: Have you tried using the sIEve tool? My understanding was that teh updatepanel was doing this regardless of if JQuery was on the page or not. The fix was just written in JQuery?

Comment: Well there isn't any jQuery loaded, so the plugin won't run, and I used sieve to find the problem in the first place before posting the question.

Comment: Ok didnt read the first line where you said you used sIEve. I just tried now - with your code sample and sIEve and it is sitting on the exact same memory every time. When I goto the 'somepage.aspx' which I have as an empty page - it drops back down as I would expect it to. I cannot replicate your issue so unless you can give me something - a web form that I can test live for example.. or a project in skydrive?

Comment: Tried on Windows 7 32 bit, running on cassini and on IIS

Comment: Edited with pastebin links to recreate easier hopefully.

Comment: Cool thanks. What happens when you click 'Show in use'? Also what version of sIEve?

Comment: There are 20 controls in use before clicking the update panel button, and 23 after. The version I'm using is hopefully the newest. I grabbed the source and compiled it less then 2 weeks ago.

Comment: nope. I am using the downloaded binary. I will try the source. This is waht I see . https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=C9AB521A41E19D63&id=C9AB521A41E19D63!108 I think you should be able to see this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5443/discussion-between-rangitatanz-and-asawyer)

Answer (score 0):

could you please try this change:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<script>
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(my_init);
   function my_init() {
       document.getElementById("UpdatePanel1").innerHTML = "";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I certainty will, however it'll have to wait until next Tuesday!

Comment: This didn't make any change, it is still reporting the memory leak.